# How to reload a shiny app when CSV file changes

Tags: r, csv, networking, shiny

I have a shiny app which generates a distance matrix. It reads a database saved in a csv file, load as a data.frame and then it calculates the distance matrix.

This app runs in a host and is used in the same network by other pc using `options(shiny.host = '0.0.0.0')` and `options(shiny.port = 5050)`.

The main problem is that when the csv is upload, the new information is not available for the shiny app due to the csv is already read, and the people that is using this app through browser is not able to stop and run again the shiny app in the rstudio to reread the csv data.base.

Is it possible to reload automatically the app when the csv is modified? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [reactiveFileReader()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html) in this scenario.

Comment: Also, a CSV file is not a database.  Your problem demonstrates one of the many reasons why!

Comment: thanks! In case of use reactiveFileReader(), how can I combine using read.csv2()?

Comment: Pass `read.csv2` as reactiveFileReaders `readFunc` parameter. Just read the documentation.

Comment: then the returned object, lets say fileData
fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'data.csv', read.csv2)
should be accessed through fileData() ? Can I then filter it like a usual df?